# How to use a PHP variable as an URL for an iframe element

Tags: php, forms, url, iframe

I'm very new to PHP (Learning it at CodeAcademy) and I wanted to make a web browser kind of thing using an `iframe`. This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
print $url;
?>

<form name="input" method="get">
Url: <input type="text" name="url" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The block of code above is a .php file. My problem with this is that the iframe leads to the URL of my domain slash the URL you enter. A little better explanation [is here](http://creativecloudinc.x10.mx/Test.php).

I tried using a `$partial = substr($url, x, y)` and making the *iframe* lead to `echo $partial` so that the original domain is cut out and only the URL you entered is in the iframe URL. That didn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check if the URL has a "http://" then proceed
else add a "http://" by your script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
print $url;
if (strpos($url,'http') === 0) { //found at position 0
    //ok
} else {

    if ((strpos($url,'google') === 0) or
       (strppos($url,'some.other.site1') === 0) or 
       (strppos($url,'some.other.site2') === 0))  // here all the knowns SSL - Sites (this can not be the ultimate solution)
    {
        $url = 'https://'.$url;
    } else {
        $url = 'http://'.$url;
    }

}
print '<br/>'.$url; 
?>

<form name="input" method="get">
Url: <input type="text" name="url" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for some websites, but not all. Are the websites that don't work (E.g. Google or YouTube) preventing this on their side? Thanks btw!

Comment: Your right.  Google has SSL (https://) so you have to check these URLs too and handle it separately for each adress.  Youtube works whith http:// but somehow does not display. -> I think YouTube will have a explanation. --> sorry have no better solution

Answer (score 1):

whenever your input is something like "google.com" the iFrame is going to look in your current directory for a file named "google.com"