# Apache - Streaming HTML5 video without making a webpage for each video

Tags: html, apache, video, raspberry-pi, playstation

I have an Apache 2.2.22 webserver running on Raspbian (RasPi Debian). I have .mp4 files in a folder that I can stream flawlessly to my web browser locally or over the internet.

My Playstation 4, however, won't take a link to a file and stream it; It needs an HTML player to stream the video. I don't want to create a player for every video. I can't make a player where you type the video name and hit play, because the names are too long and there are too many of them.

I don't know any way to get passed this without having to create an HTML page for every video, or at least an HTML page that includes every video.

EDIT:

I noticed when I viewed the source of a video in Google Chrome, this came up:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
<source src="http://10.0.0.21/media/blahblahblah.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to force the Playstation (or any browser?) to use this? Instead of the browser (google chrome) automatically applying this HTML to the MP4 video?

Comment: Any server side (that is, PI-side) script can generate a page. You could use PHP to generate it on the fly, or a simple bash script to pre-generate them on demand.

Comment: How would I go about the PHP method?

Answer (score 2):

The Playstation 4 will play a `HTML5` video if it's in the correct format, as you noticed above.

The [specs](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/gb/ps4/music/mp_format_m.html) for `MP4` are:

```
Video: H.264/MPEG-4 AVC High Profile Level4.2
Audio: AAC LC, AC-3 (Dolby Digital)
```

In addition you'll have to make sure the `moov atom` is at the start of the file to be able to start the playback immediately

With Apache you can do redirects. Eg. `http://example.com/play/video_id` can be redirected to a scripted page that uses the video ID to generate a HTML5 player on the fly.

If you want to avoid creating a script (eg: `PHP`) that generates the `HTML` page dynamically based on the `MP4` files in a directory the alternative is to use an open-source media server.

An example is the [Plex Media Server](https://plex.tv/downloads). It has a Linux version and there are articles on how to [stream to PS4](http://wololo.net/2014/07/04/ps4-media-server-how-to-stream-all-videos-from-your-local-network-to-your-ps4/). There's also [RasPlex](http://www.rasplex.com/) and [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/download/images/) and others if you fail to install Plex on Raspberry Pi.

As a bonus you get a nice interface.

Comment: I used Plex before, however it requires me to buy a membership if I want to stream over the internet. That is why I stopped using it.

Comment: When I try to use a direct link to a mp4 video on my PS4, it says "Data not supported". I know it can play HTML5 video if it is in a form within the HTML page, but I'm not sure if it can take direct links like you say it does.

Comment: No, no direct links. It works only in HTML `<video>` iff the file is encoded to specs. You can use one of the other media servers or learn web scripting.

Comment: For encoding and compressing these videos for streaming, I use Handbrake. I set Anamorphic to None; Framerate to Constant; Constant Quality to 23 RF; Audio to 128kbps Dolby Pro Logic II AAC (avcodec); Video to H.264 (x264).

Comment: That is why I wanted to use PHP to load a `<video>` form on every direct link so that it will play on my PS4. Unless the PS4 automatically ignores the file if it is a direct link, it should work.

Comment: With Apache you can do redirects. Eg. `http://example.com/play/video_id` can be redirected to a PHP page that uses the video ID to generate a HTML5 player.

Comment: I will try this, but I'm not sure if the PS4 will ignore the redirect and say Data Not Supported or if it will acknowledge the redirect and continue on. I will have to find out.

Comment: How would I go about creating a redirect? I tried to find out how but I can't seem to figure out how. I do not want to create another virtual host, so I found that there is the default one `000-default` located in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` but it doesn't end in a `.conf`, it has no file type. So I added `RedirectMatch (.*)\.mp4$ http://10.0.0.21/media/index.php?id=$1.mp4` to `000-default` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried adding that line (And even a simple `Redirect`) to `apache2.conf`, `000-default`, `default`, and even a file I created called `default.conf` located in the `sites-available` folder.

Comment: You should redirect only the URLs that start with a specific prefix because you still need access to the direct video link within the browser.  If you redirect all `mp4` requests then the `<video>` tag will also try to load the PHP file and will fail.

Comment: Where should I place my Redirect line anyway? apache2.conf? 000-default? default? default.conf?

Comment: I awarded the bounty to you for your support. It turns out I didn't even need any of this. I found that using my [first question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451162/how-to-use-a-php-variable-as-an-url-for-an-iframe-element) worked! All I need to do is type the directory (which is /media) and hit go. Then I can navigate to whatever video/audio I want on my PS4. I think I will make it even easier so I don't have to type /media or even hit go, all I have to do is enclose everything in a big iFrame as a simple fix! :)